# Uninitialised Warnings - C Programming

Tags: c

I have written the following code and when I try to run it, I get the following warnings:

- warning: variable 'money' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  GetData (money, product);
- note: initialize the variable 'money' to silence this warning
  int product, money, change;
- warning: variable 'product' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  GetData (money, product);
- note: initialize the variable 'product' to silence this warning
  int product, money, change;
- warning: variable 'change' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
  CalculateChange (money, product, change);
- note: initialize the variable 'change' to silence this warning
  int product, money, change;

I have also typed an arrow to the relevant line. I have been trying to figure out how to fix this problem for an hour now. If you could please help, it would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void GetData (int money, int product)
{
  // Asks user how much was the product and how much they paid the cashier. //
  printf("\nHow much was the product?\n");
  scanf("%d", &product);

  if((product < 5) || (product > 95) || (product %5 != 0))

  printf("\nInvalid number!\nNumber has to be a multiple of 5 and cannot be less than 5 or 
  more than 95.\n");

  else printf("How much did you give to the cashier? \n");
  scanf("%d", &money);

  if (money < product)
  printf("You did not give enough money to the cashier!");

  return;
}

void CalculateChange (int money, int product, int change)
{
  // Calculates the amount of change needed. //
  int fifty = 0;
  int twenty = 0;
  int ten = 0;
  int five = 0;

  change = (money - product);

  fifty += change / 50;
  change %= 50;

  twenty += change / 20;
  change %= 20;

  ten += change / 10;
  change %= 10;

  five += change / 5;
  change %= 5;

  return;
}

void PrintResults (int fifty, int twenty, int ten, int five)
{
  // Prints the amount of coins needed. //
  printf("\nThe number of fifty cents: %d", fifty);
  printf("\nThe number of twenty cents: %d", twenty);
  printf("\nThe number of ten cents: %d", ten);
  printf("\nThe number of five cents: %d", five);

return;
}

int main ()
{
  int product, money, change; <------
  int fifty = 0;
  int twenty = 0;
  int ten = 0;
  int five = 0;
  char response;

do {

  GetData (money, product); <-------

  CalculateChange (money, product, change);

  PrintResults (fifty, twenty, ten, five);

  printf("\nWould like to quit the program? Enter y or n\n");
  scanf("%c", &response );
  response = tolower (response);
  printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");

} while (response != 'y');
  printf("\nQuitting program...\n");

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your functions never change the variable `money` in main(), that's why. You need to study pointers next.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Free Kodak? Not even sure that that means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass reference to variables in GetData() else they are not modified by the function. I assume the compiler thinks that as they are not passed as references, they are inputs and thus should be initialized.

Same for change variabel in CalculateChange

Answer (score 0):

The `money` and `product` variables are indeed uninitialized when `GetData` is called. Passing their addresses will make the values passed have a useful value (i.e., their addresses which are, of course, initialized).

With respect to `money` and `product`, the `GetData` procedure modifies them but their values are lost after `GetData` returns. You should pass the address of `money` and `product` and modify `GetData` to properly reference and dereference them. That way, after `GetData` returns, the rest of the code can see the values written to them.

The new call in `main`:

```
GetData((&money, &product);
```

The new `GetData` signature:

```
void GetData (int *money, int product)
```

And then within `GetData`:

- change `product` and `money` to `*product` and `*money`
- change `&product` and `&money` to `product` and `money`

The same thing goes for `change`.